# Which is better? Native App or hybrid App?

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7, mobile

I want to develop a simple App for iOS, Android and windows phone.

I just wondered that a simple HTML5, JS and CSS combination can work in all of these platforms.

I want to know **which one will be efficient?**

No problem with time and coding. But if i can achieve everything with HTML5-JS itself, i will chose Hybrid development. I want to know the **major difference between the Native and Hybrid Development with example**(I know that the main difference is HTML5-JS supports cross platform).

Note : I am not making a game app.

Comment: There is a real good article about this. Hope it will help
http://sealedabstract.com/rants/why-mobile-web-apps-are-slow/

Comment: Thank you @andykkt The article is good about the memory management issue!

Comment: looks this will clear your question http://ionicframework.com/present-ionic/slides/#/30

Comment: @BEJGAMSHIVAPRASAD Thank you for sharing a nice link. It seems that the times are changed :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In my experience, these cross-platform solutions like PhoneGap and others never really hold up to expectations unless the app you're developing is super simple. Even basic things like transitional animations and small UI tweaks will be an uphill battle using these tools.

Native development might take longer (if you're building an app for more than 1 platform), but the advantage is that you get full control over what you're making. Performance-wise, native development is still, and will probably always be, far ahead from cross-platform development, simply because it doesn't have the overhead of being nested within a browser, or any other run-time interpretive platform.

Also, from my experience, the myth of being able to write code once and have it work on all platforms instantly is a sort'v holy grail. Many people claim to have achieved it, but you will always find yourself writing platform specific code (in the form of "if explorer, if safari, if chrome" etc).

My advice, write a solid architecture for your app. Build the app once in one platform, work out all the glitches in the design, then copy the design to other platforms. It'll take you a little bit longer, but the strength of your app, and the flexibility to add / change features and other small things in your app will be worth it.

As an example, take Facebook. Their previous app (if you remember) was a cross-platform app. It was slow, non-responsive, would crash all the time and was practically unusable. About a year or so ago, after countless complaints, they released an update with their native app, and suddenly, all those problems disappeared (well, at least most).

Comment: What I like though with Hybrid approach is that it is fast to get result since no need to wait when your device our emulator is ready to update changes. With hybrid one, often you need just press F5 in your browser. Like with http://ionicframework.com/ also you may reuse your mobile code in your website version of that app you develop.

Comment: but what i think if application in unresponsive then it is wastage of time on developing hybrid applications.

Answer (score 6):

The main difference is about UI component which is the main thing in an app. You can't achieve the native look and feel like native dialogs, notifications and native animations in a Hybrid app.

> I want to know which one will be efficient?

Efficiency is not an issue, Hybrid app will be a single app that will support multiple platforms which is cost and time effective.

**PROS of Hybrid app**

1. Cost effective, A single app will be developed thereby saving cost
   paid to developer for making app in different platform.
2. Time effective, Time will be saved for making different app for
   different platforms.
3. Will Update very fast, Unlike you update from google playstore the
   app will be updated on the server end only and you do not need to
   re-install it again.
4. Smaller in size. As the resources used for support of multiple
   screens will be handled by HTML .

**CONS of Hybrid app**

1. No look and feel like native app.
2. App will not even show static behaviour, if server is down.

If you are willing to compromise with the UI , Then you should go with Hybrid app.

Comment: in CONS of hybrid app, you say - 2) Needs to develop different apps for each platform which increase cost. I think it is just a controversy to your PROS of Hybrid app - 1) Cost Effective

Comment: Updated answer, check now

Comment: @Brontok "cost and time effective", "smaller in size, updating fast" -- regarding what? Could you please be more precise. There are costs in requirement analysis, development, testing, project management, marketing, tools, and indirect costs for hiring and training developers for a particular platform and tool set. IMHO, your PROS and CONS as stated, do not make sense.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I guess i have made myself clear.

Comment: Hybrid apps and even normal web apps (using Application Cache) can be used offline with no internet connection

Comment: ok @JitenderDev !!